# What is the default tick mark function for FrameTicks?

Tags: plotting, ticks

According to the [documentation of `Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html), a ticks function

> The tick mark function func[Subscript[x, min],Subscript[x, max]] may
>   return any other tick mark option

For example,

```
tickFunc = Subdivide[#1, #2, 6] &;
Plot[x, {x, -0.1, 3}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {tickFunc, Automatic}}]
```

Will show

[image]

**But I want to know what is the default tick mark function when setting `Ticks` to `Automatics`?**

A simple manipulate like

```
Manipulate[Plot[x, {x, -0.1, n}, Frame -> True], {n, 1, 200, 1}]
```

does show some definite feature of ticks, for example, number of ticks is always between 4 and 8. But I failed to construct a tick mark function behave as default. Does anyone have ideas?

Comment: You might be interested in `FindDivisions[]`: `FindDivisions[{-0.1, 3}, {7, 6}]`

Comment: Hi, @J.M. I don't quite get it. What do you mean?

Comment: Look carefully at the ticks in `Plot[x, {x, -0.1, 3}, Frame -> True]`, and then look at the result of `N[FindDivisions[{-0.1, 3}, {7, 6}]]`. Notice anything?

Comment: @J.M. yeah, the division is the same except -0.5. But I still don't understand how to make the default tick mark function. Because, the tick number is changing, not fixed.

Comment: @J.M. Oh, I seems understand what you mean now. Thank you so much! : )

Answer (score 5):

You can get a fairly close approximation using the internal functions `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` and `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks ``:

```
GraphicsRow[{
    Graphics[
        {}, PlotRange->{{0,1},{1,10}},Frame->True,AspectRatio->1
    ],
    Graphics[
        {}, PlotRange->{{0,1},{1,10}},Frame->True,AspectRatio->1,
        FrameTicks->{
            {
                Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity}],
                Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity,Identity}]
            },
            {
                Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity,Identity}],
                Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity,Identity}]
            }
        }
    ]
}]
```

[image]

You'll notice that the origins are different.

If you look at the output of plotting functions, you will sometimes see these internal functions:

```
Options[LogPlot[x, {x, 1, 10}], Ticks]
```

> {Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}}

Comment: Great, Thank you so much. I actually looked into `FullForm` of `Graphics` and found this ``Charting'ScaledTicks``, But I didn't realize that it is already a tick mark function. But I found it is not the origin that can be different. For example, compare ``Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][-0.1, 3]`` and ````Plot[x, {x, -0.1, 3}, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}], Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}]}, {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}], Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}]}}]````